# All types of Ads in Facebook Ad Library API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I try to use [Facebook Ad Library API](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/api/?source=archive-landing-page)  to search and find ads from particular page ids, but it is restricted to political ads only?! Yes, this is also mentioned in the docs, but I have found several pages saying that the Facebook Ad Library API is now (03/2019) open to all kinds of ads not just political ones. Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.facebook.com/business/help/2405092116183307?id=288762101909005

> All active ads a Page is running across Facebook Products are visible in the Ad Library. You can search for an advertiser to view the active ads running from the advertiser's Page.

---

> For ads about social issues, elections or politics, you can search by Page name or keyword, and then filter by: […]

---

> Ads that are not about social issues, elections or politics will only be discoverable through visiting a Page in the Ad Library and will not surface in keyword searches.

So, you can access *all* ads for a particular page, if you search for that particular advertiser, and then go check what ads they are running.

If you want to search adds by *keyword*, then the results will be limited to those from the social issues, elections or politics categories.

Comment: This sounds awesome! Thank you very much! I hope I can set this up now :)