# Authorization and login needed - Facebook Graph API - Ad Library

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

This is my first time with the Facebook Graph API, I am desperate, but willing to learn. I try to use [Facebook Graph API - Ad Library](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/api/?source=archive-landing-page) in order to find Ads for specific pages. But even starting with the simple FB example wasn't successfully. So my **GET** request

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/ads_archive?search_terms=california&ad_type=POLITICAL_AND_ISSUE_ADS&ad_reached_countries=['US']&access_token={access_token}
```

results in this error:

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "Application does not have permission for this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "error_subcode": 2332002,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Authorization and login needed",
    "error_user_msg": "For access to the API you need to be authorized and logged into Facebook.To begin authorization, you can visit facebook.com/ID.",
    "fbtrace_id": "---"
}
```

}

I am verified, but not logged in when using the script of course?!

Comment: Did you supply an actual access token? (Or did you just leave `access_token={access_token}` at the end unchanged …?)

Comment: yeah, use my access token.

Comment: Sorry, don’t know what exactly the problem is then. I get the same error when I try to make the request in Graph API Explorer – but I don’t have my identity confirmed, so that’s rather the expected result then. Suggest you double-check if your identity really shows as confirmed.

Comment: Checked that multiple times now :( This is frustrating! Thanks for trying! Do you know if I need any permissions for the app while developing?

Comment: I receive results for political ads, not for none political ones?! This is strange. Would be awesome if someone could help me...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59085263/10955263

Comment: But according to your link I should get all?! I haven‘t used the search term, only page ids and country.